# Printing to PDF in Notepad++ from command line

Tags: notepad++

I want to print some xml files to PDF (using Microsoft Print to PDF) from the command line. In order to preserve syntax highlighting, I would like to print via Notepad++. The only batch print command I could find is `-quickPrint` (https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/command-prompt/), which apparently does not offer any options for printer settings etc. Is there any way to get the trick done?

Answer (score 0):

check this it might work for you

```
for /r %%x in (*.c) do (
  print /d \\YOUR_COMPUTER_NAME\cutepdf "%%x".pdf
)
```

> OR

```
print /d \\YOUR_COMPUTER_NAME\cutepdf "%%x".pdf
```

Comment: Unfortunately that would not preserve Notepad++ syntax highlighting. Is there no way via Notepad++?

Comment: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/3987 check this post

Comment: Ok, so it seems there is no native solution to the problem atm (alas I do not have time to dig into customized workarounds). I was just wondering if there is something I missed. Thank you. In case some "notepad++ guy" reads this post: CMD PDF printing would be a useful feature.